Matching word boundary does not work in C
I am trying to find out whether a full word, say test, exists in a sentence and I'd like to do it in a case-insensitive manner. I took advantage of regex capabilities in C and used \b in the pattern. Here is the program
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char* hay = "This Is a TEst, or not!";

    regex_t regex;
    if (regcomp(&regex, "\btest\b", REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE)) {
        printf("compilation failed\n");
    }

    regmatch_t match[1];
    if (regexec(&regex, hay, 1, match, 0) == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("couldn't match\n");
    }
}

When I run this program, it prints couldn't match but the sentence clearly contains the TEst word. Can someone point out the problem?

It seems you need to write "\btest\b"

\b is the backspace character. Perhaps whatever library you're using (PCRE?) requires an actual backslash and a b character so \\b?

Even with escaping it properly, posix extended regular expressions don't have word boundary assertions.

And while you test to see if regcomp() failed, all you do is print a message and then keep on going like it succeeded. That's not going to turn out well.

You need to use a PCRE library to get the \b escape sequence for word boundaries. https://www.pcre.org/

There are two issues. \b is a back-space character.  Even if you fix this by doubling the backslashes, \\b, regcomp does not recognize that as a pattern, and will search for a backslash followed by a b character.
To make this work, you need to adjust your regular expression to match the capabilities of the regex engine (see the regex(7) manual page).
Change your regex to: "[^[:alnum:]]test[^[:alnum:]]", and you will have more success.
Update: Note that this regex will also return the boundary characters.  If you need to preserve the word being tested for, use "[^[:alnum:]](test)[^[:alnum:]]", and adjust your match[] array appropriately so that you can get the matched data.
Update 2: As @barmar pointed out, this won't work for text at the beginning or end of the line.  The regex would need to be changed to "(^|[^[:alnum:])(test)([^[:alnum:]]|$)" to handle that.

This won't match a word at the beginning or end of the string.
